# One to Many Annotation list control Hibernate

Tags: java, android, hibernate

I've been dealing with this, now i want to take control of this. Due to data size, I have to control the list which was populated by Hibernate.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="members") 
private List<Members> membersList;
```

So the memberList can grow upto 100, The Sql of android cannot not take it. I meant the huge size of list stored to internal database.

Is there anyway to control the list size before saving to android internal database?

Thanks,
Pusp

Comment: Is it a JPA project on Android?

Comment: Yes, are you specific about anything, Even i meant this one to ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<>(20);

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your type of collection.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="members") 
private Set<MembersList> memberList;
```

**UPDATE**

The documentation says:

> Naturally Hibernate also allows to persist collections. These persistent collections can contain almost any other Hibernate type, including: basic types, custom types, components and references to other entities. The distinction between value and reference semantics is in this context very important. An object in a collection might be handled with "value" semantics (its life cycle fully depends on the collection owner), or it might be a reference to another entity with its own life cycle. In the latter case, only the "link" between the two objects is considered to be a state held by the collection.
>
> As a requirement persistent collection-valued fields must be declared as an interface type (see Example 7.2, “Collection mapping using @OneToMany and @JoinColumn”). The actual interface might be java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or anything you like ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

Link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-mapping

Comment: Thanks, for your comment, will it solve please explain